# Is there any difference in these codes?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to make a new design. I design it with two processes which are synchronous and asynchronous. I generally give reset in the asynchronous process which is shown first code snippet. However, someone just told me that is a mistake. In her knowledge, I should give the reset statement in the synchronous process. I also checked the schematic for the first one and saw it is connected correctly to flip-flop's resets.

```
sync_proc : process(clk_i)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk_i)) then
            do smt..      
        end if;
    end process sync_proc;
```

```
async_proc : process(some signals) 
    begin
       if(reset_i = '1') then
            reset smt..
        else
            do smt..
        end if;
    end process sync_proc;
```

Above is my code and below is what she suggested.

```
sync_proc : process(clk_i)
    begin
        if(reset_i = '1') then
            reset smt..
        else(rising_edge(clk_i)) then
            do smt..      
        end if;
    end process sync_proc;
```

I am wondering that, is there any differences between these states? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a VHDL `process` as *a little bit of software that models a little bit of hardware*. With your approach, you have two little bits of hardware driving the same signal, ie a short circuit. With her (correct) approach, you have one little bit of hardware (a flip-flop) driving one signal.